# azure pipeline New-AzVM : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory

Tags: azure-devops, parameters, credentials

Im using the script below to deploy a new vm from an existing image using a pipeline:

```
New-AzVm
-Credential $(credential)
-ResourceGroupName "RG"
-Name "Dev-VM"
-ImageName "Image"
-Location "West Europe"
-VirtualNetworkName "*****"
-SubnetName "*****"
-SecurityGroupName "**************"
-PublicIpAddressName "myImagePIP"
```

but I got this error

> (##[error]Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name Credential.)

Even if the parameter is already set. I don't know why it keeps asking for an Credential parameter.

could you please help me? do you have any idea?

Comment: could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you're not the only one looking for this! Also investigating how to be able to do it. My first guess, since you are using Azure, I'd store user and password(or only the latter) on an Azure Keyvault, and create a "session" out of it... Which is nonsense, to my oppinion because you are using a Service connection, that already has permissions over the RG you want to create the VM...
At least hope this helps you getting forward!

... or! Use ARM Templates or Terraform... I'm trying to avoid that at this stage...

Hope to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

So I've achieved the solution by doing this code below. In my case I'm creating based on an image, but should work the same way.

Basically, the credential, is the localadmin user you want to create while deploying the VM. Use something that looks like this:

```
$user = "theUserYouWant"
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString "Apassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential –ArgumentList $user, $pw

 New-AzVm -ResourceGroupName $(AzureVMResourceGroup) -Name $(AzureVMName) -ImageName $(AzureImageName) -VirtualNetworkName $(VNetName) -SubnetName $(SubnetName) -Credential $cred
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is going to solve the issue, but I'm going to add it anyways, hoping someone will find it useful.
The error `Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters` is pretty straight forward. But what's causing it might not be that obvious.

In my case, it was an extra space after specifying the params that lead to this error in the pipeline. VS Code extension picks this up as a warning, not an error.

`This line has a backtick at the end trailed by a whitespace character. Did you mean for this to be a line continuation?`

[image]